# How to use best foreach and use paginate after query?

Tags: laravel

I have written a code:

```
foreach($request->get('brand') as $brandId) {
    $query[] = $productCategory->products()->whereStatus(1)->whereProductsBrandId($brandId)->get();
}
$result = [];
foreach ($query as $bulk) {
    foreach ($bulk as $child) {
        $result[$child->id] = $child;
    }
}

$products = $result->paginate(16);
```

How to clean this query in laravel?

Comment: what is `$productCategory` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "how to clean this query", but you could use `whereIn` and get rid of the for loop, like this:

```
$brandIds = $request->get('brand');

$products = $productCategory->products()
    ->whereStatus(1)
    ->whereIn('products_brand_id', $brandIds)
    ->paginate(16);
```

Comment: what is `$productCategory` ?

Comment: @N69S Based on OP code, I'm assuming that it's Eloquent model